# JSON mapping in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

So I have this JSON

`https://bitcoinpayflow.com/orders{"order":{"bitcoin_address":"1NwKSH1DJHhobCeuwxNqdMjK5oVEZBFWbk"}}`

No I want to reference the bitcoin_address

So first I strip away the string at the beginning

```
        var stripped = data.substring(33);
        alert(stripped);
                var btc = stripped.orders.bitcoin_address;
        alert(btc);
```

I get the first alert, but not the second. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `stripped` is still just a string. You need to parse it into an object. You can use the native `JSON.parse` method to do this:

```
var stripped = JSON.parse(data.substring(33));
```

Also, you are referencing the `orders` property, which doesn't exist. It's `order`.

Note that `JSON.parse` is not supported by older browsers. You can use [this polyfill](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to make sure it's always available.

Comment: Thanks! I did use 'order' before. This was just hastily rewritten for stackoverflow.

I didn't downvote? I'm waiting till the time limit passes so I can tick.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to decode json - string - use eval

```
var bitcoins = eval('(' + json_string + ')');
```

And access `bitcoins['order']['bitcoin_address']` 
But it a bit unsafe. Upper method is more safer.

Comment: No, the easiest way to deal with a JSON string is to use `JSON.parse`. You should not need to use `eval` for this.

Comment: Using eval is generally a bad idea. Try to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Omg i know it but it is works too. If i write this method that it doenst mean that i use it

Comment: @DenisErmolin - Then why promote bad practice?

Comment: I didnt promote bad practice. I comented that your way is safer to use. He must know all possible methods and bad too.

Comment: @DenisErmolin - Fair enough, that is true.

Answer (score 1):

I would use JSON.parse as follows.

```
$.post('php/whatever.php',{data:dS},function(res){
    var o=JSON.parse(res);
    var bitcoins=o.order.bitcoinaddress;
},"text");
```

Comment: Why you are using "text" instead of "json" ?

Comment: That's a really good question, Denis. I started using 'text' to avoid the need for 'intelligent guess' and because I guess the model I used initially also used 'text'. I'm not sure what the practical difference would be if I made it 'json'. My initial impression is that it might remove the need for the parse step. Thwt's how the second last example appears on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/. I might need to update a heap of code! It works fine as I posted, though.